# how to store multiple values to database from pop-up window?

Tags: php, javascript, css

i am trying to use a popup window using css that accepts multiple values. For example, when I click on a particular link a new window appears with multiple input boxes. My question is how to store accepted values in database?

I am using php as server side scripting language. A simple example to illustrate the concept would be appreciated.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>

 <style>
 #overlay {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;

 }


 #overlay div {
 width:300px;
 margin: 100px auto;
 background-color: #fff;
 border:1px solid #000;
 padding:15px;
 text-align:center;
  }

</style>


 <div id="overlay">
 <div>
    <p><input type="text" id=txt name=txt /></p>
  <input type="submit" onclick="add()" />[<a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>close</a>]
 </div>
 </div>
 <a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>clck here</a>
 <script>

 function add()
 {
   alert(document.getElementById("txt").value)  

 }


  function overlay() {
el = document.getElementById("overlay");
el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
 }
</script>

 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: It's basically the same whether it's a popup window or the same window. Also, is it a true popup window or just a modal window?

Comment: There's really more than one concept at play here. What, **specifically**, is it you're stuck on? Creating the dialog? Getting data from the dialog to the server? Saving data to the database once you get it? (If it's "all of the above", you need to look up tutorials.)

Comment: As @catfish mentioned, whether the form is hidden initially or not doesn't make a difference in how it behaves. Since you added `javascript` tag to your question, I am wondering if what you are really asking for is how to do this without actually performing a page load (as would typically happen when submitting a form without any javascript/AJAX functionality)?

Comment: @catfish i want to pass values from modal window!

Comment: Then there is nothing special. It's the exact same code as it would be if everything were on one page with no modal window. Please post some code of what you have tried.

Comment: Start with something like this - http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/php-tutorials/inserting-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php#.USJmX6VwpBk

Comment: tried some code. they are working as i expected. i can read value in parent window. thanks all

Comment: (1) when 'submit' or 'ok' or 'go' (whatever the label) button is pressed, you call a js function that will grab the entered data from the fields. (2) submit these values to the php script using either GET (vars visible in url) or PUT (vars not shown in url) (3) Collect the submitted vars in the PHP script, formulate the sql to enter them into the database and finally, execute a query with the formulated sql. Nothing special, as mentioned above.